# saving a bitmap in phone

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, save

I developing kind of image editor and I having a problem with saving final image to the mobile. I'd tried code below below but when if I save once and change the image view again and push the save button I face to a problem, there is my problem: I pushed the save button but the new image did not save, just the image that I saved in first time pushing save button save again. I do not know what to do please help me.

```
    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            img1.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bp = img1.getDrawingCache();

            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File newDir = new File(root + "/insta/pics");    
                newDir.mkdirs();
                Random gen = new Random();
                 int n = 10000;
                n = gen.nextInt(n);
                String fotoname = "instaPhoto-"+n+".jpg";
               File file = new File (newDir, fotoname);
                if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
                    try {
                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                       out.flush();
                       out.close();
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " /insta/pics  ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }

             }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have run once this code `newDir.mkdirs();`

Answer (score 0):

Try This;
add this after file.delete();
file.createNewFile();